# how to append sources to custom target?

Tags: cmake

With `target_sources` we can easily add sources to target created previously, but as the manual said:

> The named `target` must have been created by a command such as `add_executable()` or `add_library()` and must not be an `IMPORTED` Target.

So how to add more sources to a target already created by `add_custom_target`?

Considering I have a project structured bellow:

```
hello
`- CMakeLists.txt      # level 1
`- hello.x
`- world/
   `-- CMakeLists.txt  # level 2
   `-- world.x
```

Is there any better way to extend the custom target created in level 1 rather than using variable `set` with `PARENT_SCOPE`

Answer (score 0):

Awards should give to @Tsyvarev

Short answer:

```
set_property(TARGET my_custom_target APPEND PROPERTY SOURCES world.x)
```

The `SOURCES` of a target can be accessed and modified by `get_property`/`get_target_property` and `set_property`/`set_target_properties`.

[set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_property.html) do support `APPEND` option:

> If the `APPEND` option is given the list is appended to any existing property value.

Comment: The whole body of your function could be implemented using a single call to `set_property` with `APPEND` keyword: `set_property(TARGET ${target} PROPERTY SOURCES APPEND ${sources})`.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @Tsyvarev could you post as the simple better answer?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the suggestion, I previously thought this simple piece of code explain itself clearly.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.