# properties of custom target

Tags: cmake, build, cmake-modules, cmake-language

I'm using [`add_cusmtom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) to do a custom build, but what properties of this target have? Perticually how can I get the list of dependencies listed in the target:

```
add_custom_target(exsdk COMMAND echo DEPENDS foo.jar bar.jar)

get_target_property(D exsdk DEPENDS)
```

`exsdk` is not found, how can I get the properties of custom target?

Comment: DEPENDS is not a valid property on any target, not just custom targets: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets.  It isn't possible to query the dependencies of a target in this way.

Comment: [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965596/how-to-append-sources-to-custom-target) (and its answer) suggests that list of files, from which custom command depends, is stored in the SOURCES property.

Comment: Based on the man page for the [get_target_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_target_property.html) `D` is the name of the variable where the value of the property will be stored

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `exsdk` is found and the code properly executes, the value of `D` is `D-NOTFOUND`, because there is no such property as `DEPENDS`. The code showed works properly. Target has any set properties, a custom target may have no properties.